# PyGame: use of pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

Tags: python, pygame

I had a look at the documentation and tried to find examples online but I didn't manage to layer my sprites. Here is parts of the code:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        ...
        self.layer = 2
 
class Tree(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen_size, tree_id):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        ...
        self.layer = 1
    
    

pygame.init()
...

sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
players = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
trees = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

Player.groups = sprites, players
Tree.groups = sprites, trees
...
    
mario = Player() 
nbtrees = 10
[Tree(size, x) for x in range(1,nbtrees+1)]


while 1:
    ...

    sprites.clear(screen,background)
    sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I removed the irrelevant parts,  event handling, collision detection and so on. The thing is, it works super fine ; the management of the collisions using the group `trees` for example goes smoothly, which seems to indicate that the groups are ok. The only problem is: whatever the values I set in the `Player` and `Tree` classes for `self.layer`, the trees (all the trees) always blit above the player.

The [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) indicates several ways to specify layers, including the following:
"If the sprite you add has an attribute layer then that layer will be used."
Which is precisely what I do, without success.

Note that I don't really "add" the sprites to the group ; I assign the groups to the classes of my sprites, because that's what I used to do with `pygame.sprite.Group()`, which is convenient and normally comes to the same. I tried using the `add()` method of the groups but it didn't change anything.

I guess that maybe I don't initialize the groups properly, but it is strange that everything works, except the layering. I would very much appreciate some working example.

Comment: As noted in my recently added answer below, the docs were incorrect but have now been corrected. The attribute is `self._layer` **NOT** `self.layer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem for one of my own programs.  I don't know why but a layer attribute is not recognized by the sprite group. My solution was to pass the layer to the group.add() method using a key word argument like so:

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    layer = 1
    def __init__ (self):
        pygame.sprire.Sprite.__init__(self)
        sprites.add(self, layer = self.layer)
```

I like to add a sprite to a group in the **init** method for convenience.

I don't think it is necessary to have multiple groups with layering.  Drawing for one group is more convenient, and a LayeredUpdate group would take care of all the layering.

Comment: Works great, thanks!
Regarding the use of multiple groups: for the drawing, indeed it is not necessary. But if you handle collisions using groups, I think it might be useful. For example if only half your sprites can be collided with, putting only them in a "collision" group (or "trees" in my example) makes it so that the collision handling has half as many collisions to compute.

Comment: @jerorx Now I see your point.  For doing this, I usually make separate groups for different types of objects.  I add the sprite to both groups.  I have one main sprite group that I use to update and draw, and others for collisions.  So in the init method I would put `sprites.add(self, layer = x)` and `enemies.add(self)`.

Comment: Indeed, I fully agree : since my last post I kept toying around and I reached the same approach as you : one LayeredDirty group containing all sprites for display, and several standard Groups containing some subsets of the sprites for collision management and all. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just spent some time working with pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates() myself.

I know this is very late but I saw this post when I was looking to figure out how to use this myself. I worked it out and wanted to answer this in the hopes of helping out the next guy.

The attribute inside the sprite has to be named **self._layer** not self.layer. Note the leading underscore in the name.

That is not what I was expecting and the documentation says "If the sprite you add has an attribute layer then that layer will be used", which does not actually tell you the proper name of the attribute but seems to suggest that it would be 'layer', though it isn't.

If you use **self._layer**, the sprite layers works as expected without having to pass it through the add() call.

In your code you would need:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        ...
        self._layer = 2

class Tree(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen_size, tree_id):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        ...
        self._layer = 1
```

and it should work.

Edit:

I have just had this corrected in the [pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates), so people probably will no longer need to come looking here to find this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I digged further myself and realised I did not try to make it work the right way. The two important things to know (and which I did not know) are:

1. The layers only work within the same group. If all the sprites in a group are on the same layer (such as Trees in your example), this group should not be a LayeredUpdates() object, just use the normal Group() object
2. The attribute "_layer" must be set BEFORE the sprite is added to a LayeredUpdates() group (this is why the answer above was not working for me). After that it is read only and a sprite's layer can only be changed via the group's change_layer() method.

Note the change_layer() method must be used on a LayeredUpdates() group, not on the sprite itself.

Here is an example:

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
players = pygame.sprite.Group()
trees = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Tree(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, all_sprites, trees)
        # sprite has been added to all_sprites group with layer 1

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self._layer = 2
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, all_sprites, players)
        # sprite has been added to all_sprites group with layer 2
        ...
        all_sprites.change_layer(self, 3)
        # sprite layer in all_sprites has been changed to 3

while True:
    all_sprites.clear(screen,background)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```